# my y rotation keeps changing even though i'm not changing it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

i am trying to rotate its x and z axis to the mouse position while not changing the y. for some reason the y keeps changing!!!
my current code looks like this

```
    public float moveSpeed = 5;
    public float maxMoveSpeed = 15;
    CharacterController body;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        body = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
             Vector3 point = new Vector3(hit.point.x, 0, hit.point.z);
            print(point);
            transform.LookAt(point);

        }
        float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");


        Vector3 moveDis = transform.forward * v * moveSpeed;
        moveDis += transform.right * h * moveSpeed;
        body.SimpleMove(moveDis);
    }
```

for some reason if i remove the player controller it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

> i am trying to rotate its x and z axis

No you are not ^^

What you are doing is

```
Vector3 point = new Vector3(hit.point.x, 0, hit.point.z);

transform.LookAt(point);
```

where [`LookAt`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html)

> Rotates the transform so the forward vector points at /target/'s current position.

which in most cases will rotate your object around the `X` and `Y` axis!

---

It is unclear what your actual goal would be in order to provide a possible solution to that, though.